# LabVIEW cannot read UDP packet

Tags: sockets, udp, labview

I'm sending udp packets from a device to my pc.

Proof: [image] [(click here to enlarge)](https://i.imgur.com/4Insz.png)

I'm using the standard "UDP Receiver VI" from LabVIEW (labview\examples\comm\UDP.llb)

But the data I sent is not displaying on the vi, even though you can see that I'm sending the UDP packet.

Please help

Labview program:

[image] [(enlarge)](http://img404.imageshack.us/img404/116/672d8c6afe69416fb5b7893.png)

Comment: Where is the capture taken, on the sender or on the receiver? Some receive side code would help too.

Comment: this is on the receiver, my pc (192.168.1.100)

Comment: Your code shows you listen on port 64100 while the udp grap shows port 64000.
You don't have to set the IP address upon opening the UDP connection.
What might happening is that your short timeout (1 second) overwrites the 'String'FP control. (you could make the timeout larger)
To effectively use the 'Stop' button move the button into the while loop.

Comment: Sorry 1024 is connected to 'message length' not timeout.

Comment: What the wireshark show on port 64000 was an older version I now work on 64100 so, that should be the problem

Comment: Why is the first line in the log blue and the two other red? Could it be that the first one is received?

Answer (score 1):

Without any LabVIEW code it's hard to see what's going wrong.
Here's a working exapmle of a sender and receiver in one VI:

[image]

Could it be that you have multiple ethernet ports on your system?
Perhaps is setting the net address on the UDP open connection an option.

Comment: I added my program, I have somewhat the same reciever. But still I don't see data. Maybe its because my sourceport is empty from my sender or my "Time to live" is 0 in my IPv4 packet

Answer (score 0):

You have spotted the port on the front panel (64100) is not the same as the port you are sending data to (64000) ?